# Force PHP use vpn connection

Tags: php, proxy, vpn

I am working on a website which contains some links.

The actual websites related to the links are filtered in my country by our government.
I need to find a way to let our visitors to surf those websites **without** demanding to use/buy any vpn connection or proxy on their own,

i.e. this website is filtered in my country: https://www.trendyol.com/
but this link is perfectly works (no restriction): http://trendyol.cipmark.com/

I need something like what "CIPMARK.com" did.

How can I do that?

Is it possible that I buy a vpn connection and somehow embed the vpn in my website and **let visitors access those websites via this vpn connection?**

If not how can I resolve this problem?

p.s. PHproxy and Glype **failed** to open those website **properly**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do that?

Short answer you can't.

Longer answer - presumably your government blocked these sites for a reason. How happy are they going to be that you are providing a means to bypass those controls?

This is not something to be done within PHP. While, in theory, you could implement a proxy in PHP which communicates over a VPN to the origin sites, in practice this is way beyond your abilities - and a sane person who was capable of doing this would not attempt it (unless they were in the business of stealing peoples details in MITM attacks).

If you're not bothered about rubber hose vulnerabilities then just host / provide facilities for your users to download TOR or similar.

Comment: consider these links please: trendyol.com and trendyol.cipmark.com , one of these links is filtered in my country other one is perfectly works without using any vpn! how this "CIPMARK" website found a way to shows Trendyol website as their sub-domain and not been effecting by filtering restriction?